# React images get cut out of the body container in mobile view

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I'm implementing an image slider with thumbnail, currently on desktop view everything works fine. But in a mobile view, if there's more than 3 images, the thumbnails get cut out of the page body. Also the slider image width doesn't decrease. How can I solve it?

```
<div style={{display:"flex"}}>
{arr.map(x=>(<img className="thumbnail" src={x.image} alt=""/>))}
</div>
```

Scss file-

```
. thumbnail {
width:300px;
height:100px
}
```

I need to display all thumbnails in rows, if screen size gets small, the image thumbnail goes to next row.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to change the **relative** length unit.

[css units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#numbers_lengths_and_percentages)

Answer (score 0):

Add style as

```
{
  display: flex;  
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: Please check this